# Please help identify an old scifi movie about an Earth with scorching hot sun

Tags: story-identification

Old movie where staying out in the sunlight causes death since it is too hot. The protagonist gets chained up outside during the day but somehow manages to survive. Wish I had more details on this, but it's been at least 15 years since I've seen it.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1643222/ -

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2V8Tqg9tIA

Comment: Please define "Old". That term is very relative. Was it a recent movie when you saw it 15 years ago? Color or black & white?

Comment: I watched the movie back in the early 90s and it was out on TV back then... I'm thinking it was a 70s or 80s movie based on the cinematronics. Color movie.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_apocalyptic_and_post-apocalyptic_fiction

Comment: This is very [tropey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lJFX7PvRC0). Can you think of any additional details? Was the protagonist male, female, white or black? What else happened? Was there a love-interest?

Comment: Protagonist is a white male. The entire story revolved around him being connected to the Earth and being the savior that brought back greenery to the Earth (while being feared by his people for being different). Once I typed that out... it does sound super tropey :(

Comment: Someone asked for an ID of this movie over on the [Movies & TV SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26486/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be [Habitat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitat_(film)) (1997). It's set in a future where the ozone layer is depleted and going out during the day is dangerous. The movie is primarily about a teenager whose family moves out to the desert so that his father - a scientist - can experiment with heat-resistant plant life. The end goal of the experiments are to restore plant life & trees to the planet, most of which has died due to the heat & intense UV radiation.

At one point during the film, the teen is tied to a post and left outside during the day, but survives due to the effect of his father's experiments.

Here's the trailer (NSFW, partial nudity):

Comment: This is it! I was so off on the age of the movie lol. Thanks for coming through!

Comment: @RubixRechvin - no problem, that's what we do here. It's usually even fun. Usually.

Comment: 1997 is _old_?  ~cries~

Comment: @Izkata, Older: The Day the Earth Caught Fire (1961): http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054790/

Comment: @WayfaringStranger The OP was the one who described it as "old" and accepted this answer, though