# A movie about sun heat

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie about the sun becoming too hot. I remember that there was a family of 4 maybe. The father and the mother and their daughter and her boyfriend.  The father didn't like the boyfriend. The family tries to hide in the tunnels.  I think in one scene they wanted to check a car but the car got bombed from being too hot.  I think too there was someone trying to rob them or something like that.  The movie was around 2010 or something like that maybe before too but it was colored.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?

Comment: I saw it on TV, I was just switching between channels and this movie caught my attention

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82488/please-help-identify-an-old-scifi-movie-about-an-earth-with-scorching-hot-sun

Comment: Yeah I saw this question and unfortunately it's not Habitat.

Comment: "The father didn't like the boyfriend" — how ever do they come up with these outlandish science-fiction concepts!?!?!

Comment: Ah yes, 2010, right around the time when movies started having color.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps this is [*Meltdown: Days of Destruction*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478207) (2006)?  It has a small group of people trying to escape a global heatwave caused by the Earth's orbit being altered by an asteroid near miss.

> Despite scientist Nathan's warnings, his boss continues an experiment meant as publicity for his satellite firm: exploding an asteroid. Instead it splits, and the major piece, the size of Iceland, changes course to earth. It is deflected but so close that it shift our course closer to the sun, causing rapid extreme heating, hopefully only mid-term. Nathan warns his sister, TV journalist Carly, and **she her lover, police detective Tom. He brings his unruly daughter Kim, her ex-con lover C.J.** and her mother, nurse Bonnie, when Nathan offers a flight to a friend's Arctic weather station. Tom takes charge of a dangerous trip to the airport, as everywhere on earth things catch fire and people fight for water, transport and sheer looting.

One of the [reviews](https://m.imdb.com/review/rw2915092/?ref_=m_tt_urv) remarks on exploding cars.